# Is possible to get YouTube trendings by country?

Tags: api, youtube-api

Is possible to get videos on YouTube trending page by country with YouTube Data API?

Answer (score 0):

You can make API request to retrieve a list of the trending videos, and add a regioncode to filter you results
[Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to the api documentation.